# If Gravity acts on the particles in the gas, why don't they accumulate on the lower surface and fall down?

Tags: pressure, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

A quantity of gas is enclosed in a metal cylinder fitted with a piston. There are very many gas molecules.The cylinder walls are thermally conducting. Now, the question...

Comment: Hmmm... could you tell me the mass of each molecule? If you can then multiply the gravitational constant with the mass of the earth divided by the distance squared. Do you think it would be a massive force????

Comment: But they do accumulate to lower surface. The effect will be very small however on <1m cylinder. But if the cylinder would be a height of the mountain, there would be light mountain air in the top of the cylinder.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_pressure_variation#In_the_context_of_Earth.27s_atmosphere

If you would begin at equally dense situation (non equilibrium), they wouldn't fall down forever, because eventually the gravitational force would be countered by the pressure of the gas.

Comment: Well, how about considering that it is an ideal gas, then by the assumptions of the ideal gas, the mass of the molecules is very small...

Comment: Dont forget that the gasses are not idle particles they are in constant motion with each other. This motion makes them impossible to get collected in a single place. This motion is enough to overcome the gravity. Please refer the kinetic theory of the gasses.

Answer (score 1):

As Mikael Kuisma remarked, gas particle do accumulate at lower altitude. Consider two volumes $V_u$ and $V_l$ that are vertically thin as compared to their horizontal extend, which are separated by a distance $H$. A tube of negligible volume connects $V_l$ to $V_u$. A gas particle of mass $m$ in volume $V_u$ has a potential energy of $mgH$ as compared to a gas particle of the same mass in $V_l$. In accordance to Boltzmann's law, we find for the density of particles in the upper volume

$n(H)=n(0)\exp\left (\frac{-mgH}{kT} \right )$,

so for a 1-m long gas cylinder filled with N$_2$ at 300 K, the density at the top is 99.989% of the density at the bottom.

It is interesting to note that Lindemann and Aston [Phil. Mag. 37, 530 (1919)] suggested to use a gravitational potential or centrifugal fields to separate isotopic species. The latter approach is used in ultracentrifuges to enrich uranium.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the comments, the gas particles do accumulate at the bottom of the cylinder to some extent. This is essentially why the atmosphere becomes "thinner" as the altitude increases. 
The exact circumstances of how the gas would behave are also dependent on the particles' kinetic energy and the thermal environment. If the thermally conductive cylinder is placed in an environment under Standard atmospheric temperature and pressure and we take a substance that remains gaseous under these conditions, the thermal equilibrium between surroundings and gas would allow it to maintain a constant temperature and therefore kinetic energy.
This constant average kinetic energy means that the particles can still "bounce" around the container but as a result of gravity they would tend towards the bottom of the cylinder.

Answer (score 0):

As OP wished, assuming just ideal gas, we have for N ideal gas particles

$$H(\{r_i\},\{p_i\}) = \sum_i^N (mgz_i + \frac{p_i^2}{2m})$$

We get a [Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) factor

$$P(\{r_i\},\{p_i\}) = \Pi_i^N {e}^{-mgz_i/k_BT - \frac{p_i^2}{2m}/k_BT}$$

We can calculate the density

$$\rho(r) = \frac{< \sum^N_i \delta(r_i-r) >}{< 1 >} $$,

where the notation <> means integrating over all degrees of freedom. $<1>$ is the partition function. The integrations over momentum cancel each other. The $r_i \leftrightarrow r_j$ symmetry of Hamiltonian allows to replace the sum with multiplication of N and just considering term $r_1$. Now integrations wrt. $r_2 \ldots r_N$ cancel each others out. We get

$$\rho(r) = N \frac{\int dr_1 \delta(r_i-r) e^{-mgz/k_BT}}{\int dr_1 e^{-mgz/k_BT}}$$.

Assuming container with surface area A and extending from 0 to L, we get

$$\rho(r) = \frac{N e^{-mgz/k_BT}}{A \int_0^L e^{-mgz/k_BT}}.$$

Let's define

$$\rho_0 = \frac{N}{A \int_0^L e^{-mgz/k_BT}},$$ and we have derived the density profile of an ideal gas in a gravitional field, just using statistical mechanics.

$$\rho(r) = \rho_0 e^{-mgz/k_BT}$$.

Thus, we actually get a same distribution that was described here, as density and pressure are proportional, assuming constant T: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_pressure_variation#In_the_context_of_Earth.27s_atmosphere